# Cannot set Assigned Approver as ‘Queue:Queue_Name’ in Approval Steps of Approval Process using Metadata API

Tags: metadata-api, approval-process, queue

If the queue does not contains parent Object as supported Object but doesnot contains childObject as supported Object user can set Queue as approver for a approval process created on child Object. But same does not works with API.

> Steps for replication

1. Create a parent object 'ParentObj__c'.
2. Create a child Object'ChildObj__c' with Parent as 'ParentObj__c'.
3. Create a queue 'TestQueue' and add 'ParentObj__c' to its list of supported Objects.
4. Create a approval process on 'childobj__c' using UI.
   ApprocalProcess -> Approval Process Jump Start Wizard -> Select
   Approver -> automatically assign to queue. -> Select TestQueue from
   Lookup -> Save
5. Approval process is created successfully
6. When the same approval process 'childobj__c.a1.approvalProcess' is create
   using Metadata API, Approval process is not created. **The user gets
   the below error :- ' Approval step Step_1 references Test_Queue,
   which doesn't exist as a queue .'**

Answer (score 0):

Well, after setting the bounty I tried some other things. Turns out the queue didn't have the proper sObject assigned.

So, for instance, if you want to have an approval process on a custom object, make sure that object is selected in the Supported Objects section on the Edit page of the queue. Note that detail parts of master-detail relationship are not selectable, you have to select the parent.